# Which event is called when I press on a part of the tab bar?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uitabbar

An example:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `UITabBar`, set the [`delegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007521-CH3-SW12) and implement `UITabBarDelegate`s [`-tabBar:didSelectItem:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006930-CH3-SW5).
With `UITabBarController` it is `UITabBarControllerDelegate`s [`-tabBarController:didSelectViewController:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006932-CH3-SW1).